# What is the dimension of the difference of two vectors in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, vector, linear-algebra

I tried to find the difference between two vectors on python colab. It returns a square matrix with the dimension being the number of rows of the vectors. As in `np.subtract(y,X@genet).shape` where `y.shape` returns `(60,)` and `X@genet` returns `(60,)`. It is expected that `np.subtract(y,X@genet).shape` should return `(60,)` but it returned `(60,60)`.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Quick question - are you sure one of those isn't `(60, 1)`?  see the [numpy broadcasting docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Without a runnable example your question isn't reproducible - see the guide to creating a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sure your shapes are correct? if they are the same size then the resulting size would be the same.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> y = np.ones(60)
>>> y
array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
   1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
   1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
   1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
>>> y.shape
(60,)
>>> x = np.ones(60)
>>> x.shape
(60,)
>>> np.subtract(y, x).shape
(60,)
```

[compute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSFgp.png)

It appears one of your arrays are the wrong shape (ie)

```
>>> y = np.ones(60)
>>> x = np.ones((60,1))
>>> np.subtract(y, x).shape
(60, 60)
```